# Process terminates with HUP signal despite starting with nohup

Tags: c++, unix, signals, solaris, nohup

I'm quite new to solaris. I have this problem thats bugging me for sometime now.

I start a process in solaris as 
`nohup <binary>`

I do this so that my process would not get SIGHUP, the process will not terminate even after I exit from my shell.

I tested this out, by exitting from my shell.
It works as expected,the process still runs.

Problem:
When my process is idle for too long, I see the following line in dmesg..

`[ID 702911 auth.error] [29069] Run idle timeout reached (32400 seconds)`

Then my process gets a SIGHUP, and terminates.

I'm struggling with the following questions...

1. Which process writes this timeout message in dmesg? How can I find it out?
2. How come my process still get a SIGHUP despite starting with nohup? Are there any other means for a process to get a HUP signal?

Note: I tried `kill -1 <my process id>` . Then my process terminates because of the HUP signal.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What does `psig <your process id> | grep "^HUP"` say? It should say `ignored`. Maybe something in your program is resetting the SIGHUP handler.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I get
`HUP     caught  handler         RESETHAND,NODEFER`
So this means, that the program has infact received a HUP signal?

Comment: Not quite. It means that something in your program, possibly one of your ACE/TAO library routines, has told the OS that it wishes to catch SIGHUP and run some code when it is sent (it registered a handler). And because of the RESETHAND flag, it means that once SIGHUP is sent and caught, the handling of that signal reverts to the default (unless the program chooses to re-register the handler) and another SIGHUP will terminate the process.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, you were spot on. I'm quite sure this is what thats happening in my program